# How to parse JSON array objects to string array objects in JMeter

Tags: arrays, json, jmeter

I have the following JSON. I want the JSON array objects of technicalSettings (two objects in this case but can vary based on the API response) into a string array without loosing any text and want to loop through the string array to add few more elements and to form a new JSON and store the new JSON in a string variable.

```
{
  "data": {
    "statusCode": 200,
    "success": true,
    "technicalSettings": [
      {
        "program": "C:/temp/abc.exe",
        "actions": "9",
        "file_name": "abc1",
        "new_file_name": "newabc1",
        "version": "2.0.0.0",
        "product_name": "abc",
        "description": "abc",
        "eventdate": "20160601120000",
        "autoVoiceProfile": {
              "autoVoices": [
                {
                  "autoVoiceLanguage": 0,
                  "autoVoiceMessage": [
                    {
                      "name": "AV1",
                      "duration": "1.200000",
                      "checksum": "2d4c44d142bc0391b980b8a103ab35cc23d8f7820895cb6025cf3c829139336c",
                      "fileName": "/usr/g/db/user_autoVoiceMsg7.aifc",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "AV1",
                      "duration": "0.600000",
                      "checksum": "9538cf287d178964dcb57a05b7acbc00e04c800a9aaed0b22f5433d9dc79d80c",
                      "fileName": "/usr/g/db/user_autoVoiceMsg8.aifc",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "AV2",
                      "duration": "2.800000",
                      "checksum": "050acdb345e079da1371623c9727bc16d166db0a0b47687ff93d736ddf37cde8",
                      "fileName": "/usr/g/db/user_autoVoiceMsg9.aifc",
                      "id": 5
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "AV2",
                      "duration": "4.100000",
                      "checksum": "c5a6a39df38505c0c22b75d9ea7781a1755e9c8c9f435e08034f579361ba751c",
                      "fileName": "/usr/g/db/user_autoVoiceMsg10.aifc",
                      "id": 5
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "messagesitefilename": null
            }
        
      },
      {
        "program": "C:/temp/abc.exe",
        "actions": "9",
        "file_name": "abc2",
        "new_file_name": "newabc2",
        "version": "2.0.0.0",
        "product_name": "abc",
        "description": "abc",
        "eventdate": "20160601120000",
        "autoVoiceProfile": {
              "autoVoices": [
                {
                  "autoVoiceLanguage": 0,
                  "autoVoiceMessage": [
                    {
                      "name": "AV1",
                      "duration": "1.200000",
                      "checksum": "2d4c44d142bc0391b980b8a103ab35cc23d8f7820895cb6025cf3c829139336c",
                      "fileName": "/usr/g/db/user_autoVoiceMsg7.aifc",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "AV1",
                      "duration": "0.600000",
                      "checksum": "9538cf287d178964dcb57a05b7acbc00e04c800a9aaed0b22f5433d9dc79d80c",
                      "fileName": "/usr/g/db/user_autoVoiceMsg8.aifc",
                      "id": 4
                    },
                    {
                      "name": "AV2",
                      "duration": "2.800000",
                      "checksum": "050acdb345e079da1371623c9727bc16d166db0a0b47687ff93d736ddf37cde8",
                      "fileName": "/usr/g/db/user_autoVoiceMsg9.aifc",
                      "id": 5
                    }
                  ]
                }
              ],
              "messagesitefilename": null
            }
      }
    ],
    "library": {
      "version": 6,
      "dmIdVersion": 5
    }
  },
  "success": true,
  "statusCode": 200,
  "errorMessage": ""
}
```

I used the JSON Extractor but it is failing when split into array since the array objects contains multiple ",".

String strPublishTechSettings = "${pPublishTechSettings_ALL}";

String[] PublishTechSettings = strPublishTechSettings.split(",");

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts as:

- in case of compilation caching enabled only first value will be used for all iterations
- it conflicts with [Groovy GString Template Feature](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/docs/next/html/documentation/template-engines.html#_gstringtemplateengine)
- it might be resolved into something causing compilation failure or unexpected behaviour

so change this line:

```
String strPublishTechSettings = "${pPublishTechSettings_ALL}";
```

to this one:

```
String strPublishTechSettings = "${pPublishTechSettings_ALL}";
```

and your test should start working as expected[image]:

in the above example `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see JavaDoc for all available functions and [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on other JMeter API shorthands available to JSR223 Test Elements